# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException Cannot see and get table and its elements

Tags: javascript, java, asp.net, selenium

Can anyone give me a hint, how can I get elements of table, while table itself is generated dynamically. I found the javascript, which generates the table, but I cannot get the elements of table and at the point of getting elements selenium gives following error org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.

I tried to get the elements with Xpath, but selenium cannot see the elements and table itself, because the data is being retrieved from database or after loading the table is hidden, though the table and elements are visible to user, but in source code of webpage there is no such table.

Comment: go to developer options > console > type $x("your xpath") > then enter and share the result

Comment: I inserted it in the post, because it didn't fit in comments field

Comment: I found answer, I had that issue, because I needed to wait for that element to appear.